# @CustomTestApplication value cannot be annotated with @HiltAndroidApp

Tags: dagger-2, dagger-hilt

If the Application has a Custom Application object. It is needed to annotate this with @HiltAndroidApp
ex:
@HiltAndroidApp
class AppCore: Application

Appcore has some initialization logic which is needed for the app to run

Now in the Instrumentation tests We also need to Extend the custom Application object.
@CustomTestApplication(AppCore::class)
interface HiltTestApplication

This gives an error @CustomTestApplication value cannot be annotated with @HiltAndroidApp

Is there any other way of using HILT in instrumentation tests with custom Application objects

```
public abstract interface HiltTestApplication {
                ^
  @CustomTestApplication value cannot be annotated with @HiltAndroidApp. Found: AppCore
```

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/161413134

Answer (score 6):

As suggested in the issue tracker. Can you abstract your initialization logic into a base class, say `BaseAppCore : Application` then in your prod application extend it `@HiltAndroidApp AppCore : BaseAppCore` and then for tests make Hilt generate a test app based on your abstract one, `@CustomTestApplication(BaseAppCore::class) interface AppCoreTestApplication`. It might be best to file this issue in https://github.com/google/dagger/issues

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a new class with the `@HiltAndroidApp` annotation, which would be different from the one you will use in your tests.

```
open class AppCore: Application
{
 // Existing code.
}
```

```
@HiltAndroidApp
class ProdAppCore : AppCore
{}
```

```
@CustomTestApplication(AppCore::class)
interface HiltTestApplication
```

If you are using Robolectric, you can set:

```
application = $packageName.HiltTestApplication_Application
```

And in your AndroidManifest.xml, set:

```
<application
        android:name="$packageName.ProdAppCore"
```

where `$packageName` is the package where ProdAppCore and HiltTestApplication class have been defined.

This is also discussed here: https://github.com/google/dagger/issues/2033